# Finding Locale from Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Sprinng 3.0.

How do I find the current locale set by a LocaleResolver within an annotation-based controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can declare an argument of type `Locale` in your controller method:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView foo(..., Locale locale) { ... }
```

**See also:**

- [15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)

Comment: I can confirm that if you are using a `@RestController` this also works. For a REST API, you can then set a certain locale for testing by using the `Accept-Language` header in the request.

Answer (score 1):

[`LocaleContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html#getLocale--) can be used, especially to obtain the `Locale` outside of a controller method.

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```